# Trouble with Protractor and Angular 2 application with Angular sign in

Tags: angularjs, angular, protractor

I've been having issues getting my protractor e2e test to work. The application that i'm testing is angular 2 and the sign in is through a separate angularjs site. I'm trying to create a test for logging in, checking that my site loads correctly with the given credentials, and then logging out. I can log in just fine, navigate to my site, and then navigate back to the auth page. However, once it gets there, protractor stops before it clicks the Sign Out button and the webdriver stays stuck on the page instead of closing.

Here is my Page Object code with the functions:

```
`var LoginPage = function() {

  this.loginEmail = element(by.css('[id="email-input"]'));
  this.loginPassword = element(by.css('[ng-model="loginForm.password"]'));
  this.signInButton = element(by.css('[name="signIn"]'));
  this.twoFactorCodeInput = element(by.css('[id="code-input"]'));
  this.verifyTwoFactorButton = element(by.css('[name="verifyTwoFactor"]'));
  this.signoutButton = element(by.css('[ng-click="signout()"]'));


  this.navigate = function() {
    browser.get('http://spectrumxg.dev:3007');
  };

  this.LoginAs = function (username, password) {
    this.loginEmail.sendKeys(username);
    this.loginPassword.sendKeys(password);
    this.signInButton.click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    this.twoFactorCodeInput.sendKeys('0000000');
    this.verifyTwoFactorButton.click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    browser.get('http://xpect.spectrumxg.dev:9000');
  };

  this.LogOut = function () {
    browser.get('http://spectrumxg.dev:3007');
    browser.refresh();
    browser.sleep(3000);
    this.signoutButton.click();
  };

};
module.exports = LoginPage;`
```

Here is my test:

```
var LoginPage = require('../pageObjects/login.po.js');
var loginPage = new LoginPage();
var DashboardPage = require('../pageObjects/dashboard.po.js');
var dashboardPage = new DashboardPage();

describe('logging in', function() {

  loginPage.navigate();
  loginPage.LoginAs('s@a.com', '123');
  browser.sleep(3000);

  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  });

  it('should be able to successfully login', function() {
    expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('xpect.spectrumxg.dev:9000/#/dashboard');
    expect(dashboardPage.navbar.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should be able to successfully logout', function() {
    this.signoutButton.click();
    browser.sleep(3000);
    expect(loginPage.loginEmail.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

I am able to click on the Signout Button in the Element Explorer. Not sure if it has something to do with it going from AngularJS to Angular 2 and then back to Angular JS.

Here is my webdriver log:

```
    15:17:36.429 INFO - Executing: [execute async script: try { return (function (rootSelector, callback) {
  var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);

  try {
    if (window.getAngularTestability) {
      window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
      return;
    }
    if (!window.angular) {
      throw new Error('window.angular is undefined.  This could be either ' +
          'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +
          'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\'s ' +
          'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');
    }
    if (angular.getTestability) {
      angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
    } else {
      if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {
        throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +
           ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');
      }
      angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').
          notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    callback(err.message);
  }
}).apply(this, arguments); }
catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [body]])
15:17:36.572 INFO - Done: [execute async script: try { return (function (rootSelector, callback) {
  var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);

  try {
    if (window.getAngularTestability) {
      window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
      return;
    }
    if (!window.angular) {
      throw new Error('window.angular is undefined.  This could be either ' +
          'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +
          'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\'s ' +
          'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');
    }
    if (angular.getTestability) {
      angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
    } else {
      if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {
        throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +
           ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');
      }
      angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').
          notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    callback(err.message);
  }
}).apply(this, arguments); }
catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [body]]
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue (with an Angular 1.4 app though).

Comment: fwiw my current theory is that this is related to outstanding $timeout / $interval functions. Make sure you cancel all of these. In your unit tests you can use $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()